# AndEngine confusion unregistering an IUpdateHandler

Tags: android, andengine

My apologies if this question is a bit newbie-ish.  I'm using AndEngine and my question is specific to that framework.  Suppose I create an IUpdateHandler as follows:

```
    this.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            doUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

In my doUpdate() method I have the information I need at some point to determine that it's time to unregister the IUpdateHandler.  There's a method, unRegisterUpdateHandler(), which sounds perfect for this purpose, but in order to use it I need to pass in some reference to the updatehandler, and I have no such reference.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code you provided creates anonymous instance of `IUpdateHandler` to which you have no reference. Instead you should firstly store created `IUpdateHandler` in some variable e.g `IUpdateHandler myHandler = new IUpdateHandler() {...});` and then register it using `this.registerUpdateHandler(myHandler)`. Having reference to handler you can unregister it using method you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry for the brain fart.  This is the answer.  Thanks Damian.

Comment: Hi i want to know , do there is any way to know Update handler is registered or not..

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside updatehandler you can unregister it by this. If your updatehandler is registered to scene

```
this.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        doUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
         if (something) Scene.this.unregisterUpdateHandler(this);
    }
});
```